# inserting data to table located in windows azure

Tags: android, database, azure, azure-storage

This is the very first time, i am working with Windows Azure. So, please ignore my silly mistake if found.

I am having problem with inserting record to the database located at windows azure. This is my java code:

```
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceTable;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.ServiceFilterResponse;
import com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.TableOperationCallback;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class HomeScreen extends Activity {

    EditText et_id, et_acc_mas_id, et_amount, et_sender_id, et_borrower_id,
            et_entry_date, et_cancel_flag;
    Button btn_save, btn_clear;
    EditText[] et;
    private MobileServiceClient mClient;
    private MobileServiceTable<AccountLiner> mToDoTable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

        try {
            mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "https://xxxxxxxx.azure-mobile.net/",
                    "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", this);

            mToDoTable = mClient.getTable(AccountLiner.class);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        et_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et_acc_mas_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        et_amount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        et_sender_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        et_borrower_id = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        et_entry_date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
        et_cancel_flag = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);

        et = new EditText[] { et_id, et_acc_mas_id, et_amount,
                et_sender_id, et_borrower_id, et_entry_date, et_cancel_flag };

        btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        btn_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                addItem();
                for (EditText e : et) {
                    e.setText("");
                }
            }
        });

        btn_clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btn_clear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                for (EditText e : et) {
                    e.setText("");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void addItem() {
        if (mClient == null) {
            return;
        }

        Log.i("add item", "add item");
        // Create a new item
//      AccountLiner item = new AccountLiner(Integer.parseInt(et_id.getText()
//              .toString().trim()), Integer.parseInt(et_acc_mas_id.getText()
//              .toString().trim()), Float.parseFloat(et_amount.getText().toString().trim()),
//              Integer.parseInt(et_sender_id.getText().toString().trim()),
//              Integer.parseInt(et_borrower_id.getText().toString().trim()),
//              et_entry_date.getText().toString().trim(), false);

        AccountLiner item = new AccountLiner(Integer.parseInt(et_acc_mas_id.getText()
                .toString().trim()), Float.parseFloat(et_amount.getText().toString().trim()),
                Integer.parseInt(et_sender_id.getText().toString().trim()),
                Integer.parseInt(et_borrower_id.getText().toString().trim()),
                et_entry_date.getText().toString().trim(), false);

        // Insert the new item
        mToDoTable.insert(item, new TableOperationCallback<AccountLiner>() {

            public void onCompleted(AccountLiner entity, Exception exception,
                    ServiceFilterResponse response) {

                if (exception == null) {
                    Log.i("insert", "insert");

                } else {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

When i check, i don't find any records and i get an exception caught through printing stack trace:

```
06-11 18:15:34.318: W/KeyCharacterMap(25959): No keyboard for id 0
06-11 18:15:34.318: W/KeyCharacterMap(25959): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-11 18:15:49.558: I/add item(25959): add item
06-11 18:15:49.798: D/dalvikvm(25959): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 6889 objects / 339584 bytes in 68ms
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959): com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceException: Error while processing request.
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959):    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceConnection$1.onNext(MobileServiceConnection.java:122)
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959):    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceClient$7.handleRequest(MobileServiceClient.java:728)
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959):    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceConnection.start(MobileServiceConnection.java:93)
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959):    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:77)
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959):    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.RequestAsyncTask.doInBackground(RequestAsyncTask.java:1)
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:371)
06-11 18:15:51.118: W/System.err(25959):    at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:199)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:256)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:375)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:164)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:348)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    at android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient.execute(AndroidHttpClient.java:243)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.ServiceFilterRequestImpl.execute(ServiceFilterRequestImpl.java:71)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    at com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.MobileServiceConnection$1.onNext(MobileServiceConnection.java:102)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    ... 10 more
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:168)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:366)
06-11 18:15:51.148: W/System.err(25959):    ... 23 more
06-11 18:15:51.158: W/System.err(25959): Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: TrustAnchor for CertPath not found.
06-11 18:15:51.158: W/System.err(25959):    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:149)
06-11 18:15:51.158: W/System.err(25959):    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:202)
06-11 18:15:51.158: W/System.err(25959):    at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:164)
06-11 18:15:51.158: W/System.err(25959):    ... 24 more
```

Please help me finding my problem.

Comment: Even tried to change https:// to http:// still not working and shows different stackTrace from the above mentioned one.

Comment: Did you get this fixed? I am having the same error.

Comment: @JoelDean check this link: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-with-data-android/

Comment: @shree202 You can answer your own question here. Why not do it? :)

Comment: @AlfredoCavalcanti Yes sir. Surely I would surely try to add this ASAP. If you came across the error, same as i got, you can try the link i posted in above comments. It will definitely fix your error. I think i did something wrong with my code, this is why the posted code didn't work. Try the link, you'll find the alternate way to insert data, and you'll be through... Sorry for inconvinence.